# magento filter product collection by category name

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, magento-1.9.3.6

I am using magento 1.9.3.6. In magento how to filter the product Collection by catery Name also.

Note: Am already Filtered the product by`name` and some Custom attributes.
My Code is

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'name', array('like' => '%' . $query . '%')), array('attribute' => 'brand', 'finset' => $brandCollection), array('attribute' => 'model', 'finset' => $modelCollection),));
```